# Optimal way to find minimum distance between two vertices in a graph

Tags: algorithms

What is the most computationally efficient method for finding the distance between two given vertices in a graph?

Comment: Do you know anything about the edge weights in the graph? Are they all $1$? Are there negative edge weights?

Comment: No it doesnt say anything about the edge weights. It just say this "State the best run-time achievable to compute the distance between two given vertices in a graph, and state the basic algorithm used here"

Comment: The best runtime achievable is $\mathcal{O}(m + n)$ (linear in the number of edges and vertices), and it is achieved by using the breadth-first search (BFS) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Look for *bidirectional Dijkstra's algorithm*.

Answer (score 0):

If edge weights are $1$, you can use the breadth-first search algorithm which runs in $\mathcal{O}(m + n)$ time, where $m$ and $n$ are the number of edges and vertices respectively. This is the best complexity you will get.

If edge weights are all non-negative (but not necessarily $1$), you should use Dijkstra's algorithm.

If your graph has negative edge weights, then you can't use Dijkstra's algorithm. I would suggest using the Bellman-Ford algorithm.